# LUIS ai datetime prebuilt entity

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am creating a luis application for bot. I am using date time prebuilt entity in my App.It is not mapped properly.For ex: when i use camry 2015 it is mapped correct where as i gave camry 2016 it is not mapped to date time.what is the reason for it?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still seeing this? Maybe it was a bug and got fixed. I just tried it and both camry 2015 and camry 2016 got identified correctly. Also pay attention to punctuations, those can make a difference too.